# How can I build a C# list using data from my Class

Tags: c#, list, class

I am a junior developer with very little experience using a class.  I have create a class which looks like this.

```
 public class Employee
{
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Hours { get; set; }
    public string Minutes { get; set; }
    public string Pages { get; set; }
    public string Certs { get; set; }
    public double HourlyRate { get; set; }


}
```

}
I use this code to populate the Class via the click of an asp button

```
 Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.EmpID = ddlSpecialist.SelectedValue;
        emp1.Hours = txtDetailsHours.Text;
        emp1.Minutes = txtDetailsMinutes.Text;
        emp1.Pages = TxtDetailsPages.Text;
        emp1.Certs = txtDetailsCertified.Text;
        emp1.HourlyRate = HR;
```

I assume everything is working and I am populating the class with records.  I now want to build a list so can pull the data from the Class.  And this is now where I am stuck I instantiate the list using

```
List<Employee> Emp = new List<Employee>();
 foreach (var item in Employee)
        {

        }
```

But from there I cannot figure out how to add records from the class.

I tried to build a foreach loop but I get a error "Employee is a type, which is not valid in the given context"  I can find several example where the values I am trying to get from the class are hard coded but nothing where the data comes from the class.

The goal is to have a a group of textboxes with data.  When the users provides the data in those boxes they would click a button that would take the values in the textboxes and store it in the class.  The code behind would then clear the textboxes of their values and the user can now enter another batch of information that would get added to the class.

When the user was done entering the records I would want to loop thru the class and for each record in the class perform some simple mathematical calculations.  So it kind of works like a calculator.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. `Employee` isn't iterable, so you cant use it in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Did you mean to write `foreach (var item in Emp)` ?

Comment: Are you trying to build a list with a single employee in it?

Comment: `Emp.Add(emp1)` will add the employee to the list.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Looks to me you want a [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1)  instead?

Comment: It seems you are assuming classes store records of all instances of that type? That is not the case. If you want a storage location of employees, you have to build that yourself. You could use a List<Employee> and add your employees there so that later you can loop over that list and get all employees in the list.

Comment: I added more details to the question to explain myself a little better.  User would provide info in an aspx controls, one of which is a combo box, then click a button.  Data would get written to the class and all textboxes would be cleared for next record.  I can't  build a list due to a post back when the button is clicked.

Comment: Please see my new addition to my answer - Are you using MVC pattern?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the function of a class.  I am thinking the class could be used like a database but I am beginning to think that is not the case.  Or I have still not done a good job of explaining what I need.  What function does the get serve in the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**

Okay, your new edit makes things a little clearer, but you still don't say what you wish to do with your data once it's been added to your Employee class.

Assuming that you're using ASP.NET, your code is probably structured in a pattern known as MVC, where M(for Model) is your Employee class, your ASP page is the V (for View) and you'll have another class/file that is the C (Controller).

Your UI page is used to populate an instance of Employee, as you've said, this is then passed through the controller to be stored, typically in a database of some sort.

The controller should provide either an empty instance of Employee to the View when it opens.

The "submit" button should trigger/call a `Task` in the controller to store the Employee instance. This may be on a list locally in the Controller or by direct call to the database, depending on your caching protocol.

Once stored the Controller should provide the View with a new, empty Employee instance.

Does this seem to make sense and is this relevant to your situation?

**original answer below**

Your question is a little unclear.

If you are gathering your data to populate your Employee instance from an ASP page and then looking at storing that data onto a remote server then how that is done will be dependent on your remote API.

You could get all of the data from any class properties
Something like this?

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.EmpID = "1234";
        emp1.Hours = "46";
        emp1.Minutes = "32";
        emp1.Pages = "5";
        emp1.Certs = "none";
        emp1.HourlyRate = 12.45;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append($"{emp1.GetType().Name}:");
        var props = emp1.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                            .Where(p => p.CanRead);

        foreach (var p in props)
        {
           sb.Append($"{p.Name}=");
           sb.Append($"{p.GetValue(emp1).ToString()};");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

`Employee:EmpID=1234;Hours=46;Minutes=32;Pages=5;Certs=none;HourlyRate=12.45;`

Comment: Thank you you explanation and demo was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

On this way you can add values to list.

```
public class Employee{
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Hours { get; set; }
    public string Minutes { get; set; }
    public string Pages { get; set; }
    public string Certs { get; set; }
    public double HourlyRate { get; set; } 
};

public static void Main()
{
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee() {EmpID = 1},
        new Employee() {EmpID  = 2}
    };

    //or this way

    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    employees.Add(new Employee() {EmpID = 1});
    employees.Add(new Employee() {EmpID = 2});


    foreach(var employee in employees)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(employee.EmpID);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you this does build a list but I am not able to get my vaules out of the class

Comment: After your edit, correct me if I didn't understand right, you want to create object from Employee class and add that object to list. I think that my answer works ok and would be something that you search for. Can you better explain this "I am not able to get my vaules out of the class"? Becuase if you loop through list in foreach loop you can access to all data in your Employee class.